# Dynamically show MainWindow.xib

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have a tab bar control application in XCode 4 and before the main window is supposed to show, a login screen comes up and the user must login. In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in my appdelegate.m file, i redirect to the login view:

```
UISignInController *USIC = [[UISignInController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UISignInView"
                                                                bundle:nil];
[_window addSubview:USIC.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When the user logs in successfully, at the end of that function I want load mainwindow.xib. How do i do that? I tried to load it like a view but that doesn't work. How can i show the mainwindow.xib file dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead load the MainWindow normally, and push your UISignInController atop of it modally using `[self.viewController presentModalViewController:USIC animated:YES]`.

*Side note: use lowercase names for variables; uppercase keywords are reserved for constants and titlecase names are reserved for classes names.*

Comment: viewController is of type what? And do i put this in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in my appdelegate.m file?

Comment: Can't you guess the type of viewController from the variable name?! (that's why respecting naming conventions is also useful). And yes in appDidFinishLaunching of course.

Comment: Good point. I added the viewController and the code to the method. The login pops up just as before so im still in the same boat. How do i make the login go away so the mainwindow will load?

Comment: by dismissing the modalViewController of course, like you always do when prensentModalViewController. You should read the UIViewController documentation, and especially the View Controller Programming Guide at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS you'll find everything explained.

Comment: This wont work, because I need to get data from the login view after a user has successfully logged in and then pass it to the mainwindow and load the main window based off of the data received from login. Not just hide the mainwindow behind something and make that something disappear. Im asking because this is a tab bar control app and i dont know  any other way to load a tab bar controller unless its on the mainwindow.

Comment: Don't get what's the problem here. You can get your AppDelegate from your `UISignInController` and send your data to it before dismissing your `UISignInController`. That's quite classic in Object-Oriented Programming and in the MVC design pattern. I do such things all the time (actually in a much cleaner way, as I define a @protocol the main controller conforms to and use the delegation design pattern). Already doing this in multiple projects of mine, even passing parameters from one VC to another, so no pb here.